# tableView didSelectCell does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

No matter what i am trying, it's just dose't call it. I have set up all the `delegation` from storyboard, `numerOfItemInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is getting called as well. But no the `didSelect`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sometimes the problem is a confusion between `didSelect` to `didDeselect`.
Change your method to

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        <#code#>
    }
```

Long shot, might work. Good luck!